# MS SQL Server : Full text search Not working when using Wild Card in Contains

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to search from table using keywords and it works fine when I do not use wildcards.

```
CONTAINS(CP.Course, '"B.A" OR "B.E/B.Tech"')
```

But it does not shows any records when I use this:

```
CONTAINS(CP.Course, '"*B.A*" OR "*B.E/B.Tech*"')
```

Is there any reason for it? Since wild card is used as both prefix and suffix so any matching record should be shown. But it shows none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server full-text search does not support search by prefix asterisk.

So, while `"B.A*"` is a valid term, `"*B.A*"` and `"*B.A"` are not.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql